# How do I implement a custom required error in zod error map?

Tags: typescript, zod

I want to implement my custom zod error map messages but wonder how do I make my custom required_message in the zod map? I couldn't find it in the switch/case for `zodIssuecode`.

Before that I had to do it manually for each input in the schema.

The zod map looks like this:

```
const customErrorMap: z.ZodErrorMap = (issue, ctx) => {
    switch (issue.code) {
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_type:
            if (issue.expected === "string") {
                return { message: 'invalid_string' };
            } else if (issue.expected === "number") {
                return { message: 'invalid_number' };
            } else {
                return { message: 'invalid_type' };
            }
        case z.ZodIssueCode.custom:
            return { message: issue.message || 'custom_error' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_union:
            return { message: 'invalid_union' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_enum_value:
            return { message: 'invalid_enum_value' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.unrecognized_keys:
            return { message: 'unrecognized_keys' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_arguments:
            return { message: 'invalid_arguments' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_return_type:
            return { message: 'invalid_return_type' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_date:
            return { message: 'invalid_date' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_string:
            return { message: 'invalid_string' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.too_small:
            return { message: 'too_small' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.too_big:
            return { message: 'too_big' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_intersection_types:
            return { message: 'invalid_intersection_types' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.not_multiple_of:
            return { message: 'not_multiple_of' };
        case z.ZodIssueCode.not_finite:
            return { message: 'not_finite' };
        default:
            return { message: ctx.defaultError };
    }
}
```

The zod issue code looks like this:

```
export declare const ZodIssueCode: {
invalid_type: "invalid_type";
invalid_literal: "invalid_literal";
custom: "custom";
invalid_union: "invalid_union";
invalid_union_discriminator: "invalid_union_discriminator";
invalid_enum_value: "invalid_enum_value";
unrecognized_keys: "unrecognized_keys";
invalid_arguments: "invalid_arguments";
invalid_return_type: "invalid_return_type";
invalid_date: "invalid_date";
invalid_string: "invalid_string";
too_small: "too_small";
too_big: "too_big";
invalid_intersection_types: "invalid_intersection_types";
not_multiple_of: "not_multiple_of";
not_finite: "not_finite";
};
```